gRPC on Java takes a long time to execute
I am trying to use gRPC on java, but the first call on gRPC takes a very long time. Its taking me almost 3-4 sec for the firs call. This is what I am doing -
for (int cur_server_number = 1; cur_server_number <= totalServers; cur_server_number++) {
ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 50050 + cur_server_number)
        .keepAliveWithoutCalls(true)
        .keepAliveTime(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS) 
        .usePlaintext()
        .build();
DistributedBankGrpc.DistributedBankStub stub = DistributedBankGrpc.newStub(channel);

stub.commit(commitRequest, new StreamObserver<Empty>() {
    @Override
    public void onNext(Empty emptyResponse) {
        System.out.println("Commited on server " + serverNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        System.err.println("Commit request to Server " + serverNumber + " failed: " + t.getMessage());
        t.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        System.out.println("Commit request to Server " + serverNumber + " completed.");
    }
});
}

I am basically sending asynchronous request to 5 different servers on ports 50051 - 50055. But the very first gRPC call takes over 4-5 seconds to execute. The subsequent requests on these ports are faster. Why does this happen and how can I resolve this?

You are using a plaintext connection on localhost. have you used Wireshark to see the initial connection data flow to check if this is a client or a server problem?
